# Minecraft Windows 10 edition beta - the app can't update when it's open

Tags: windows-10, minecraft

I have a Windows 10 tablet that I recently factory reset. I had Minecraft Windows 10 edition beta installed on it before the reset, with no problems. After the reset, while I was re-downloading MCW10, the download got interrupted by a WiFi outage. After the WiFi came back on, the app finished downloading, but I got the error "the app can't update when it's open". Remember, at this point, the app isn't even installed yet.

No other apps have this problem, and windows update works just fine. What can I do?

I have already tried signing out, and wreset several times. Also, every time I re-try the download, progress goes instantly from 0% to 100%, and the size of the MCW10 app download gets incrementally larger by about .5MB, even though it's not actually downloading anything.

Comment: Where would it's directory be located? If it's in "C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution" then I don't have access to it. No matter what I try, I always get 'The file or folder is in use' when trying to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix. I reset Windows update using the following steps.

1. Run *services* from the start menu
2. stop the **Windows update** service
3. change user permissions for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution to "allow" all (right-click->security)
4. rename C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution to SoftwareDistribution.old
5. reboot

After these steps, MCW10 installed as normal.